# Images need to be clicked in a specific order

Tags: javascript, css

I am making a game where you need to press the Images in a specific order. When you click the right Image it will play a note. When you press the wrong Image it will also play a sound that u are wrong and then u have to start over and click the images again till you have clicked them all in the right order. This is what I have but it is not working at the moment and I dont know why.

What is happening is that when you press the images the sound does work but for a reason the specific order I wanna press does not work. (*copied from OP comment*)

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=d?evicRe-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>puzzel3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/puzzel3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="imgMuziek">
        <img id="imgDo" src="images/puzzel3/skull.png" alt="">
        <img id="Re" src="images/puzzel3/skull.png" alt="">
        <img id="Mi" src="images/puzzel3/skull.png" alt="">
        <img id="Fa" src="images/puzzel3/skull.png" alt="">
        <img id="Sol" src="images/puzzel3/skull.png" alt="">
        <img id="La" src="images/puzzel3/skull.png" alt="">
        <img id="Si" src="images/puzzel3/skull.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <p>Music until death</p>
    <script src="js/puzzel3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript file:

```
let lastNote = null;
let errorNote = new Audio ("Audio/MuziekNoten/ERROR.mp3");
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let mouseX = e.x;
    let mouseY = e.y;
    console.log(e);
    // do
    if (mouseX > 885 && mouseX < 945 && mouseY > 94 && mouseY < 145) {
        let note = new Audio ("Audio/MuziekNoten/DO.wav");
        note.play();
        lastNote = 'do';
    }
    // re
    if (mouseX > 2 && mouseX < 43 && mouseY > 3 && mouseY < 52) {
        let note = new Audio ("Audio/MuziekNoten/RE.wav");
        note.play();
        if (lastNote == 'do'){
            lastNote == 're';
        }
        else{
            lastNote = null;
            errorNote.play();
            note.pause();
        }
    }
    // mi
    if (mouseX > 394 && mouseX < 430 && mouseY > 635 && mouseY < 672) {
        let note = new Audio ("Audio/MuziekNoten/MI.wav");
        note.play();
        if (lastNote == 're'){
            lastNote == 'mi';
        }
        else{
            lastNote = null;
            errorNote.play();
            note.pause();
        }
    }
    // fa
    if (mouseX > 990 && mouseX < 1022 && mouseY > 885 && mouseY < 923) {
        let note = new Audio ("Audio/MuziekNoten/FA.wav");
        note.play();
        if (lastNote == 'mi'){
            lastNote == 'fa';
        }
        else{
            lastNote = null;
            errorNote.play();
            note.pause();
        }
    }
    // sol
    if (mouseX > 1387 && mouseX < 1426 && mouseY > 468 && mouseY < 517) {
        let note = new Audio ("Audio/MuziekNoten/SOL.wav");
        note.play();
        if (lastNote == 'fa'){
            lastNote == 'sol';
        }
        else{
            lastNote = null;
            errorNote.play();
            note.pause();
        }
    }
    // la
    if (mouseX > 1749 && mouseX < 1783 && mouseY > 152 && mouseY < 193) {
        let note = new Audio ("Audio/MuziekNoten/LA.wav");
        note.play();
        if (lastNote == 'sol'){
            lastNote == 'la';
        }
        else{
            lastNote = null;
            errorNote.play();
            note.pause();
        }
    }
    // si
    if (mouseX > 1887 && mouseX < 1919 && mouseY > 929 && mouseY < 968) {
        let note = new Audio ("Audio/MuziekNoten/SI.wav"); 
        note.play(); 
        if (lastNote == 'la'){
            lastNote == 'si';
        }
        else{
            lastNote = null;
            errorNote.play();
            note.pause();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags. This isn't a question about the Visual Studio Code software application, and nor is there even a hint of C# code anywhere here.

Comment: What do you mean by "_it is not working_"?  What, specifically, isn't working?  There's a reasonable amount of code there and most people that want to help are unlikely to trawl through it all in order to figure out what isn't working for you

Comment: @Martin So when you press the images the sound does work but for a reason the specific order I wanna press does not work. I am a beginner in programming and am still learning.

Comment: @RandomStuff Thanks for clarifying. I've added your description into the question

Comment: @RandomStuff Why are you doing it based off mouse positions, is there any specific reason, did you check my solution, does that help?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee i had trouble clicking the images because the notes didn't play and i couldn't find the problem. a professor of mine looked at my code in its entirety and helped me. while I'm impressed with your code, I think it wouldn't fit my code at all plus I would have to tweak many other things as well. I made the sound work but now I still need the Error sound when you press the wrong image in the order. btw thanks for helping me i really appreciate it!

Comment: hey @RandomStuff maybe my demo could help to improve your code

Comment: @FabrizioCalderanlovestrees I will go take a look thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you mistakenly used "==" instead of "=" at some points, look for example here:

```
        if (lastNote == 'do'){
        lastNote == 're';
    }
```

You want to say if lastNote == 'do' then **lastNote = 're'**

This repeats throughout, so fix that and you will be good I think! And after you are done you should search about clicking HTML DOM elements, it would make your life so much easier instead of using the mouse coordinates.

Comment: It worked thanks now I just need a little fix for the first notes!

Comment: Also please know that you can attach an click handler to every image instead of using magic numbers to check the mouse position. Your code will look way better with that

Answer (score 1):

This question intrigued me so I created a small demo using the `AudioContext` object (which it seems to be [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=AudioContext)) so you don't even need to make requests to other audio resources.

The order of the notes you should play is defined in the `orderToPlay` array. The note is generated when you click on a specific list-item through its `data-tone` attribute (I've used plain text to describe the note, you could use of course an image inside the list-items)

```js
let orderToPlay = ['B','E','A','D','G','C','F'];
let orderPlayed = [];

const noteFrequencies = {
   'C': 261.63,
   'D': 293.66,
   'E': 329.63,
   'F': 349.23,
   'G': 392.00,
   'A': 440.00,
   'B': 493.88,
   'error': 60.00
}


function playTone(note, duration = 2) {
   let ac = new AudioContext();
   let oscl = ac.createOscillator();
   let gain = ac.createGain();

   oscl.connect(gain);
   gain.connect(ac.destination);
   
   oscl.frequency.value = noteFrequencies[note];
   if (note === 'error') {
      oscl.type = "sawtooth";
      duration  = .4;
   }
   else {
      oscl.type = "sine"
      gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(.0001, duration);
   }

   duration += ac.currentTime;
   oscl.start(0);
   oscl.stop(duration);
}


let notelist = document.querySelector('.notes');
notelist.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  let tgt = ev.target;
  let tone;
  if (tgt.matches('[data-tone]')) {
     tone = tgt.getAttribute('data-tone');
     
     if (orderToPlay[orderPlayed.length] === tone) {
        orderPlayed.push(tone);
        playTone(tone);     
        
        if (orderToPlay.length === orderPlayed.length) {
           orderPlayed = [];
           alert('You win');
        }
     }
     else {
        orderPlayed = [];
        playTone('error'); 
     }
  }
});


var par = document.querySelector('p');
par.setAttribute('data-order', orderToPlay.join(','));
```

```css
.notes {
   list-style: none;
   display: flex;
   gap: 5px;
   font-size: 2rem;
   padding: 0;
}

.notes li {
   border: 1px #ccc solid;
   inline-size: 120px;
   aspect-ratio: 1;
   
   display: inherit;
   gap: inherit;
   flex-flow: column wrap;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   cursor: pointer;
   
   background: #fff;
   transition: background .33s;
}

.notes li:hover {
   background: #d6e2f6;
}

.notes li::after {
   content: "(" attr(data-tone) ")";
}

.guess::after {
   content: attr(data-order);
   font-weight: 600;
   color: #9bc;
}


* {
   font-family: "Lato";
   font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<ul class="notes">
   <li data-tone="C">Do</li>
   <li data-tone="D">Re</li>
   <li data-tone="E">Mi</li>
   <li data-tone="F">Fa</li>
   <li data-tone="G">Sol</li>
   <li data-tone="A">La</li>
   <li data-tone="B">Si</li>
</ul>

<p class="guess">You need to play this notes in order: </p>
<p>When you play the wrong note you must restart the sequence</p>
```

You can also test it here: https://codepen.io/fcalderan/pen/ZELmEpo

Comment: thanks for all the effort. this will certainly be of great help. Have a nice day!

Comment: you're welcome, I have also learned new stuff @RandomStuff

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the next image that needs to be clicked in a variable, take a look at the following code snippet.

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");
let current = 0;

imgs.forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (img.id === imgs[current].id) {
      console.log("Correct Image Clicked");
      current += 1;
    } else {
      console.log("Incorrect Image Clicked, Try Again From Start");
      current = 0;
    }
    if (current >= imgs.length) {
       console.log("You won");
       current = 0;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1061142/pexels-photo-1061142.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" id="first-img" />

<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1061141/pexels-photo-1061141.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" id="second-img" />

<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1061140/pexels-photo-1061140.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" id="third-img" />
```

Comment: Thank you all people really have been helpfull!